Deploying Azure App service & define the GitHub as the Deployment Repository work well, but fail if i define the Deployment Repository as BitBucket
I am facing this weird problem, now i have an Azure App Service, and when i define its Deployment repository to reference this repository inside GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center.git the deployment worked well, here are the deployment logs:-
Command: deploy.cmd
Restoring npm packages for EOC-TeamsFx (this can take several minutes)
"C:\home\site\repository"
Restoring npm packages for tabs folder (this can take several minutes)
"C:\home\site\repository\EOC-TeamsFx\tabs"
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/abort-controller@2.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-auth@1.7.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-client@1.9.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-http-compat@2.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-lro@2.7.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-paging@1.6.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-rest-pipeline@1.16.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-tracing@1.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-util@1.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/keyvault-keys@4.8.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/logger@1.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lru-cache@10.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14 || >=16.14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated adal-node@0.2.3: This package is no longer supported. Please migrate to @azure/msal-node.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.1.0: A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.
npm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.18.4: A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.

npm notice 
added 1442 packages, and changed 24 packages in 10m
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 10.9.0

276 packages are looking for funding
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.0>
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.9.0` to update!
Building the client app (this can take several minutes)
npm notice 

> teamsfx-template-tab@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

[eslint] 
src\components\ConfigSettings.tsx
  Line 162:45:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='  eqeqeq
  Line 162:93:  Expected '!==' and instead saw '!='  eqeqeq

src\components\Dashboard.tsx
  Line 289:21:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
  Line 401:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text
  Line 409:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text
  Line 417:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text
  Line 462:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text
  Line 480:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text
  Line 499:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          jsx-a11y/alt-text

src\components\IncidentDetails.tsx
  Line 9:10:     'Checkbox' is defined but never used                                 @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  Line 1406:56:  Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function     array-callback-return
  Line 2866:58:  Array.prototype.filter() expects a return value from arrow function  array-callback-return

src\components\IncidentHistoryPDF.tsx
  Line 15:5:  Useless constructor  @typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor

src\components\Tasks.tsx
  Line 172:25:  Nested block is redundant  no-lone-blocks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  434.04 kB  build\static\js\779.329e7238.chunk.js
  338.05 kB  build\static\js\883.8bcd5626.chunk.js
  331.08 kB  build\static\js\main.6c2db15c.js
  93.84 kB   build\static\js\691.22821ef4.chunk.js
  66.35 kB   build\static\js\877.45b01877.chunk.js
  54.86 kB   build\static\js\866.a83a269e.chunk.js
  39.84 kB   build\static\js\835.632e8ee9.chunk.js
  27.57 kB   build\static\css\883.0dce1ce5.chunk.css
  23.38 kB   build\static\js\941.50b3449b.chunk.js
  16.13 kB   build\static\js\380.8e4bd4d8.chunk.js
  8.51 kB    build\static\js\62.7cedc007.chunk.js
  7.25 kB    build\static\js\618.5f0098fb.chunk.js
  6.85 kB    build\static\js\267.ed356cf8.chunk.js
  6.67 kB    build\static\js\871.935930ac.chunk.js
  5.99 kB    build\static\js\556.fc1a6ecc.chunk.js
  5.41 kB    build\static\css\62.4efa670d.chunk.css
  5.2 kB     build\static\css\941.32a31278.chunk.css
  4.52 kB    build\static\css\350.13e79219.chunk.css
  4.45 kB    build\static\js\350.62db20f3.chunk.js
  4.08 kB    build\static\css\267.17dfe22d.chunk.css
  3.07 kB    build\static\css\556.50b25da9.chunk.css
  1.36 kB    build\static\js\652.73ed0189.chunk.js
  1.02 kB    build\static\css\877.b13ad8ee.chunk.css
  207 B      build\static\css\main.6b3cb5b6.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

Creating app_offline.htm
KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\home\site\repository\EOC-TeamsFx\tabs\build' to: 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'asset-manifest.json'
Copying file: 'auth-end.html'
Copying file: 'auth-start.html'
Copying file: 'deploy.png'
Copying file: 'favicon.ico'
Copying file: 'hello.png'
Copying file: 'index.html'
Copying file: 'publish.png'
Deleting file: 'static\css\556.e4eba981.chunk.css'
Deleting file: 'static\css\62.04dc33e2.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\267.17dfe22d.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\350.13e79219.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\556.50b25da9.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\62.4efa670d.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\877.b13ad8ee.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\883.0dce1ce5.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\941.32a31278.chunk.css'
Copying file: 'static\css\main.6b3cb5b6.css'
Deleting file: 'static\js\267.bc4f5b14.chunk.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\556.e83cf9c2.chunk.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\62.6439ab13.chunk.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\877.6b8a13de.chunk.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\941.e9cd0997.chunk.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\main.369a35a4.js'
Deleting file: 'static\js\main.369a35a4.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\js\267.ed356cf8.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\350.62db20f3.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\380.8e4bd4d8.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\556.fc1a6ecc.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\618.5f0098fb.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\62.7cedc007.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\652.73ed0189.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\691.22821ef4.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\691.22821ef4.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\js\779.329e7238.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\779.329e7238.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\js\835.632e8ee9.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\835.632e8ee9.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\js\866.a83a269e.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\871.935930ac.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\877.45b01877.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\883.8bcd5626.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\883.8bcd5626.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\js\941.50b3449b.chunk.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\main.6c2db15c.js'
Copying file: 'static\js\main.6c2db15c.js.LICENSE.txt'
Copying file: 'static\media\ActiveBridgeIcon.63d90aa707db188f19d530410c6c6268.svg'
Copying file: 'static\media\ActiveIcon.556616af7441dc4f7e127127be62f21f.svg'
Omitting next output lines...
Finished successfully.      

Now our customer wants to have their code inside Bitbucket. so i did those steps:-
1)Clone the GitHub Repo locally:-
d:\TEOC>git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center.git
2)Add the Bitbucket repo:-
D:\TEOC\microsoft-teams-emergency-operations-center>git remote add bitbucket https://@*.org/ausvetcode/teoc.git
3)Run:- git fetch bitbucket
4)Run:- git add .
5)Run:- git commit -m "Saved"
6)Run:- git push bitbucket main --force
Enumerating objects: 867, done. Counting objects: 100% (867/867), done. 
Delta compression using up to 8 threads Compressing objects: 100% (522/522), done. Writing objects: 100% (867/867), 12.32 MiB | 3.55 MiB/s, done. Total 867 (delta 371), reused 797 (delta 320), pack-reused 0 (from 0) remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (371/371), done. To https://bitbucket.org/***/teoc.git
    
b0219b5...03f3075 main -> main (forced update)

And the GitHub code got copied successfully inside BitBucket*
. Then i went back to Azure App Server >> Deployment Center >> i define the repository to be BitBucket (instead of GitHub), as follow:-

But the deployment failed, here are the deployment logs:-
Command: deploy.cmd
Restoring npm packages for EOC-TeamsFx (this can take several minutes)
"C:\home\site\repository"
Restoring npm packages for tabs folder (this can take several minutes)
"C:\home\site\repository\EOC-TeamsFx\tabs"
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/abort-controller@2.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-auth@1.7.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-client@1.9.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-http-compat@2.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-lro@2.7.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-paging@1.6.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-rest-pipeline@1.16.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-tracing@1.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-util@1.9.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/keyvault-keys@4.8.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/logger@1.1.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lru-cache@10.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14 || >=16.14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated adal-node@0.2.3: This package is no longer supported. Please migrate to @azure/msal-node.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.1.0: A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.
npm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.18.4: A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.

npm notice 
added 782 packages, and changed 43 packages in 9m
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 10.9.0

276 packages are looking for funding
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.0>
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.9.0` to update!
Building the client app (this can take several minutes)
npm notice 

> teamsfx-template-tab@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TS2304: Cannot find name 'newsTabLink'.
  [0m [90m 2136 |[39m                         [33mTeamWebURL[39m[33m:[39m teamInfo[33m.[39mdata[33m.[39mwebUrl[33m,[39m
   [90m 2137 |[39m                         [33mPlanID[39m[33m:[39m planID[33m,[39m
  [31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 2138 |[39m                         [33mNewsTabLink[39m[33m:[39m newsTabLink
   [90m      |[39m                                      [31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m[31m[1m^[22m[39m
   [90m 2139 |[39m                     }[33m;[39m
   [90m 2140 |[39m
   [90m 2141 |[39m                     [36mawait[39m [36mthis[39m[33m.[39mupdateIncidentItemInList(incidentId[33m,[39m updateItemObj)[33m;[39m[0m

Any advice what might be causing this error in the deployment from BitBucket?
Here is the Error:-
Failed exitCode=1, command=npm run-script build
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine 
{\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/abort-controller@2.1.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-auth@1.7.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-client@1.9.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-http-compat@2.1.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-lro@2.7.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-paging@1.6.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-rest-pipeline@1.16.0',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-tracing@1.1.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/core-util@1.9.0',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/keyvault-keys@4.8.0',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@azure/logger@1.1.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.0.0' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lru-cache@10.2.2',\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14 || >=16.14' },\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE   
current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.19.2' }\r\nnpm WARN EBADENGINE }\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. 
Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. 
Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. 
Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. 
Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object@7.21.11: 
This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. 
Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0:
 This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated adal-node@0.2.3: 
 This package is no longer supported. Please migrate to @azure/msal-node.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: 
 This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.1.0: 
 A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated @azure/msal-node@1.18.4: 
 A newer major version of this library is available. Please upgrade to the latest available version.\r\nnpm notice \r\nnpm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 10.9.0\r\nnpm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.9.0>\r\nnpm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.9.0` to update!\r\nnpm notice\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\103.100930.002\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd


Can you clean up this question a bit.  You've got a lot pasted in there and most of it is kind of irrelevant to the problem, as far as I can tell you're good on the devops, but there's something specific about the program you're trying to build that isn't work.  This is probably something you could recreate in a development environment and troubleshoot and then go back and adjust the dependencies to fix up.

@PeterTurner what i need to do exactly from your point of view? i typed the commands i run and the logs for the successful and fail deployment .. now the question is closed any way!!!

@PeterTurner To be honest i do not see that the question is not clear... everything is already described well with all the details.. not sure what you mean be lot of pasted??? the question is are those pasted text relevant or not .. also the logs and the commands are essential part of my issue ..

THE QUESTION IS CLOSED BECAUSE IT NEED MORE CLARITY ... SERIOUSLY .. I MENTIONED THE COMMANDS AND THE LOGS FOR THE FAIL AND SUCCSEED DEPLOYMENT.. WHAT ELSE CAN MAKE THIS MORE CLEAR?

@microsft I don't think you're gonna convince anyone here to reproduce your steps from scratch.  Focusing on the problem and identifying the differences between github and bitbucket is what I'd hone in on.  I think that once you've done that, you'll probably reach your own conclusion as to what the answer is.

I think putting the actual error message (Which gets obfuscated by the scroll boxes) would be preferable.  It's a pretty interesting issue, I hope someone can help.

@PeterTurner ok separated the error from the overall logs
